# How to UPDATE a column using an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, where-clause

I have a table whose primary key is a column named `St_ID`. I want to update another column in that same (`ID`) using values stored in an array. But when I try the code below, the result is a new record with an `St_ID` value of '0' and all other columns are empty.

Note, `courseID` is a value chosen through a drop down list. Do you have any idea where I went wrong?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
   $Student = $foo[$i];
   $res = mysql_query("SELECT St_ID FROM student WHERE St_ID='$Student' ");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
   {
      $sql = "INSERT INTO student (ID) VALUES
      ('" . $_POST[$row['courseID']] . "')";
   }
}
if (!mysql_query($sql,$connectdb))
{
   die ('Error :'.mysql_error());
}
echo "The Students are add to the course <br />";
```

Comment: You want update or insert as new ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here simplified code, with only one query

```
$where = "'".implode("','", $foo)."'";
$res = mysql_query("UPDATE student set ID = courseID WHERE St_ID IN ($where)") 
         or die('Error :'.mysql_error());

 echo "The Students are add to the course <br />";
```

Comment: +1, but I would prefer the [IN operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) instead of .. or ... or ..

Comment: well , it did work but the opposite ! I want to add the courseID (is tha ID) not the St_ID , what in foo is the selected St_ID that i want to add the courseID to or update this selected records with ,

Comment: yes , to update the recored with the selected Sct_ID with this value

Comment: I got this error ! do you have anyidea why ? Error :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE St_ID IN (2011)' at line 1 (while 2011 is the selected St_ID )

Comment: @SaraS'h please check the whole query. use `die("UPDATE student set ID = courseID WHERE St_ID IN ($where)")` to see the whole query

Answer (score 0):

you select `St_ID` but try to insert `courseID`

in this line

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO student (ID) VALUES
     ('" . $_POST[$row['courseID']] . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT St_ID FROM student WHERE St_ID='$Student' 
INSERT INTO student (ID) VALUES ...
```

If you want to update that record you chose, you must use the UPDATE sql command instead;

```
UPDATE student 
SET ID=...
WHERE St_ID='$Student'
```